# User agent access to site Python in Linux

Tags: python, urllib

I am using the following code to verify my user agent id to get access to web pages:

```
url = 'http://...'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent}

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

However, I am using Ubuntu now, how do I change the `user_agent` variable to match linux standards?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example Chrome user agent for Linux:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/507.12 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.31.00.00 Safari/507.12
```

And a Firefox user agent on Ubuntu:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100001
```

Here's a command line browser's user agent on Linux.

```
Lynx/2.8.8dev.3 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1
```

They're really not that strict.  The safest user agent (from a success perspective) to use is Chrome or Firefox, but make sure to observe the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

This site may helps.

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

You can choose a linux-supported browser and then find "User-Agent"s which contains "linux".